# Validation for search input when model is a list

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, unobtrusive-validation

In the view, the model is:

```
@model List<ParamsTaskLib.ParamRecord>
```

I want to create a form with an input field which will be the DeviceID to search for:

```
public class ParamRecord
{
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9a-fA-F]{8}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Device ID (hex)")]
    public Int64 DeviceID { get; set; }

    other fields in here...
```

I tried editing the view in the following way:

```
<form method="get" >
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.First().DeviceID)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.First().DeviceID)
```

But it doesn't work obviously, it doesn't seem like it SHOULD work:)
I'm confused with how to work with a list as a model, combined with a search box...

The error I get is "Value can't be NULL" on this line:

```
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.First().DeviceID)
```

Extra clarification: the purpose of this page is to display a table which contains many lines (ParamRecord) of a specific DeviceID from the database.
The purpose of the form + input field is to supply the web server with the DeviceID of which I want to see data (a collection of ParamRecord)

This is the complete View page:

```
@model List<ParamsTaskLib.ParamRecord>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "SearchResults";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<script type="text/javascript" >
    function UpdateFunc() {
        $.get("/home/GetProgress", function(data) {
            $("#UpdatePercentage").text(data);
            if (data == "100")
                location.reload();
            else
                setTimeout(UpdateFunc, 2000);                
        });
    }

    function Update() {
        var id = $("#id").val();
        $.post("@Url.Content("~/Home/UpdateID/")" + id, function (data) {
            UpdateFunc();
        });               
        $("#UpdateAni").attr("src", "@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/ajax-loader.gif")");
        $("#UpdatePercentage").show();
    }     

</script>

<div>
    <form method="get" >
        @Html.TextBox("id")
        @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.First().DeviceID)*@
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.First().DeviceID)
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        <img id="UpdateAni" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/ajax-loader_static.gif")" onclick="Update()"/>
        <span id="UpdatePercentage" style="display:none" >0</span>
    </form>

    @if (Model != null )
    {
        <h4>ID 0x<span>@ViewBag.ID</span> , last update was at @ViewBag.LastUpdateTS</h4>
        <h3>Total @ViewBag.NumOfParams parameters</h3>
        <hr />
        <table border="1" >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Parameter Number</th>
                    <th>Device Inner ID</th>
                    <th>Device Type</th>
                    <th>Value (Int)</th>
                    <th>Value (Float)</th>
                    <th>Value (String)</th>
                </tr>                    
            </thead>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
            {   
                <tr>
                    <td>@Model[i].ParamIndex</td>
                    <td>@Model[i].DeviceInnerID</td>
                    <td>@Model[i].DeviceType</td>                        
                    <td>@Model[i].ParamValInt</td>                        
                    <td>@Model[i].ParamValFloat</td>
                    <td>@Model[i].ParamValSTR</td>                    
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    }
    else if (ViewBag.NoResults == 1)
    {
        <h3>No results for ID 0x<span>@ViewBag.ID</span></h3>
    }

</div>
```

Comment: Could you show us a more complete piece of your view and how you display your List of ParamRecords?. Normally you'd iterate over it and display each ParamRecord seperatly and Validate just for `model.DeviceID`

Comment: Do you want to add a control for each `ParamRecord` in the collection (or just the first one - in which case why is the model a collection and not a single `ParamRecord` object?

Comment: I've edited the original post, hope it makes more sense now

Comment: A bit hard to understand what you code is supposed to be doing. Are you wanting to have a textbox that you enter a value and then post that value to a controller that then returns a filtered list based on the value?

Comment: @StephenMuecke exactly

Comment: You don't bind your 'search' control to a property of your collection. You bind to to a separate property in a view model or just have an unbound textbox and then post its vaue to a method returns the filtered collection. And you should be posting the value using ajax and just update the current page rather than rendering the whole page again

Comment: Thanks, eventually I just added a jquery validation to this field and gave up on the model binding way since, as you mentioned, it just doesn't make sense